# Where (and when) Ubercart stores CC data?

Tags: drupal, ubercart, drupal-5

I use Drupal 5 with Ubercart 1 (latest) and uc_subscribe module.

I see in uc_subscribe module that CC data for recurring payment is taken from `uc_payment_credit` table, but I cannot find the place in code where data is added to this table. I grepped sources of UC1, UC2 and still have no clue how it should work. Can anyone please point me the exact line or function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubercart doesn't store credit card data, unless you are in test mode. The CC data is generally stored by the payment gateway (authorize.net, paypal, etc). Storage of credit card data can only legally be done if your site is [PCI Compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).